# getpass in pytest return OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, getpass

I'm trying to write a test in `pytest` to pass a password with `getpass` but I'm getting this error:

```
OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured
```

here is my function:

```
def test_my_password_check(monkeypatch):   
    password = 'pytestpassword'
    monkeypatch.setattr('getpass.getpass', lambda: password)
    update_passwords()
    assert keyring.get_password('testaddress', 'testusername') == password
```

I already try with:

```
import mock
@mock.patch("getpass.getpass")
def test_username_password(getpass):
    password = 'pytestpassword'
    getpass.return_value = "xxx"
    update_passwords()
    assert keyring.get_password('testaddress', 'testusername') == password
```

even with `from unittest.mock import patch` or `update_passwords.getpass = lambda: password`

All of it with the same error. What am I missing? Thanks!!

Comment: I had faced a similar issue due to keeping `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` inside one of Django's source files.